# Inserting more properties in MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb

So I'm working on a comments, I'm inserting them into collection of existing posts and I want to have more than one comment in my Mongo document.

This is how I set one property in a single document:

```
let result = await db.collection('posts').update({
_id : mongo.ObjectId(id)}, 
        {$set : {comment : req.body.newComment }})
```

So how to insert more of them in a particular document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `push` operator to do that.

```
let result = await db.collection('posts').update(
    { _id: mongo.ObjectId(id) }, 
    { $push: {comment: req.body.newComment} })
```

[MongoDB Official Documentation for push operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)